# How can I limit internet bandwidth for a daemon in linux?

Tags: linux, internet-connection, bandwidth

I can successfully throttle  a process using [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle). But how can I limit a daemon, that autostarts on boot?

Comment: It isn't a good idea to do so, since trickle runs in userspace, and the daemons run in system space. it is acceptable and secure to run userland apps that rely on systemspace components, but the reverse is dangerous. Additionally per the man pages, trickle will not work on statically linked executables, or setUID executables: http://linux.die.net/man/1/trickle if you really want to try find an init script for your daemon, and edit it to call trickle as its starting the service, but this will never work for all daemons, as trickle expects the system to be fully loaded at its runtime for depends

Comment: consider using IPTables for traffic shaping. see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/154451/throttle-bandwidth-via-iptables#154518